# Can't install Yeoman on Ubuntu because my nodejs and npm are outdated

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yeoman

I'm trying to install Yeoman via npm, but I get the following errors when I run `npm install -g yo`:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/home/marieficid/.node/bin/yo -> /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js

> yo@1.6.0 postinstall /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✖ Node.js version

Your Node.js version is outdated.
Upgrade to the latest version: https://nodejs.org

✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✖ npm version

Your npm version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g npm

✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Found potential issues on your machine :(
/home/marieficid/.node/lib
└── yo@1.6.0
```

Which is very odd because when I run `node --version && npm --version` I get:

```
v4.3.1
3.7.3
```

And when I try to run `npm install -g n` I get:

```
/home/marieficid/.node/bin/n -> /home/marieficid/.node/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
/home/marieficid/.node/lib
└── n@2.1.0
```

I tried running [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version), which only brought me more issues: Now I can't run node `--version`, only `n --version`, which returns 2.1.0, and I can't run `npm install -g n` because I get this:

```
marieficid@mariana-K46CB:~$ npm install -g n
/usr/bin/env: node: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

Which means "directory not found". What can I do? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, by the way.

**EDIT:** I think I screwed up my $PATH variable... does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I think yeoman was just letting you know that you're node and npm versions were out of date. I don't think that means yeoman wasn't installing.

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
npm install -g npm
```

not

```
npm install -g n
```

according to your output

Comment: I get the same error when I try to run `npm install -g npm`, `/usr/bin/env: node: File or directory not found`